# output feature map dimension of VGG16 model

Tags: computer-vision, conv-neural-network, feature-extraction

I saw the example of feature extraction in the [keras doc](https://keras.io/applications/) and used the following code to extract feature from input image

```
input_shape = (224, 224, 3)
model = VGG16(weights = 'imagenet', input_shape = (input_shape[0], 
input_shape[1], input_shape[2]), pooling = 'max', include_top = False)
img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(input_shape[0], 
input_shape[1]))
img = image.img_to_array(img)
img = np.expand_dims(img, axis=0)
img = preprocess_input(img)
feature =  model.predict(img)
```

Then when I output the shape of the `feature` variable, I found it is (1, 512). Why it is this dimension? 
The `print model.summary()` shows the shape of last conv layer's output after maxpooling is (7, 7, 512), this is the dimension that I expect `feature` should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank [Yong Yuan](http://yongyuan.name/) for helping me figuring this out. Since he has some problem with answering question on SO so I just put his answer here in case other people have same question.

Basically it's because there's a global max pooling layer specified in this model (as we can see in the line `model = VGG16(....., pooling = 'max', ....)` which selects the largest cell from the 7*7 cells. It's also said in keras [documents](https://keras.io/applications/#vgg16):

```
 pooling: Optional pooling mode for feature extraction when include_top is False.
```

And in the output given by `model.summary()`, we can see after the max pooling of the fifth convolution block there's actually a `global_max_pooling2d_1` layer and so the final dimension becomes 512.